# SIGABRT double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running latest ROS2 eloquent release. Node aborting on startup in rclinit()

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

GDB tells me the error is in the `rclcpp::init(argc, argv)` call which is the first statement of the node. It only started aborting after I added a yaml config file. So I added  `--cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address"` to enable the memory sanitizing features of GCC.

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==24262==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00002dfffff1 (pc 0x7f3437322962 bp 0x00002dfffff1 sp 0x7ffecf4d24c0 T0)
==24262==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
    #0 0x7f3437322961  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x28961)
    #1 0x7f3437406014 in __interceptor_free (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10c014)
    #2 0x7f3436d0a6de in __default_deallocate (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rcutils/lib/librcutils.so+0x46de)
    #3 0x7f34367308e8 in rcl_yaml_node_struct_fini (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so+0x28e8)
    #4 0x7f343676ab8e in rcl_arguments_fini (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rcl/lib/librcl.so+0xfb8e)
    #5 0x7f3436769ab0 in rcl_parse_arguments (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rcl/lib/librcl.so+0xeab0)
    #6 0x7f3436772f19 in rcl_init (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rcl/lib/librcl.so+0x17f19)
    #7 0x7f34370f5d69 in rclcpp::Context::init(int, char const* const*, rclcpp::InitOptions const&) (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rclcpp/lib/librclcpp.so+0x3d9d69)
    #8 0x7f3437212fa7 in rclcpp::init(int, char const* const*, rclcpp::InitOptions const&) (/opt/ros2/eloquent/install/rclcpp/lib/librclcpp.so+0x4f6fa7)
    #9 0x55c93cebce1a in main /home/guru/src/humanoid/ros2/humanoid/src/lss_joint_publisher/src/lss_joint_states.cpp:96
    #10 0x7f3436943b6a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x26b6a)
    #11 0x55c93ceba619 in _start (/home/guru/src/humanoid/ros2/humanoid/build/lss_joint_publisher/lss_joint_states+0xf619)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x28961)
```

Yaml file is simple, just a single parameter

```
joints: 17
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340506/sigabrt-double-free-detected-in-tcache-2/) by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2019-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've figured out that I need the node name and ros__parameters lines added to the yaml. I did this at first but I didnt realize that there is a double underscore in ros__parameters. So my working yaml is:

```
lss_joint_publisher:
    ros__parameters:
        joints: [17,18,19]
```

I still dont think a SIGABRT is a good way to handle yaml errors. lol. but I am working again. :)

---

Originally posted by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) with karma: 280 on 2019-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-22**:
I'm not entirely sure where right now, but I would suggest to report this to a GH issue tracker of one the repositories hosting this infrastructure, as I agree with you this does not seem like a proper way to handle this, and ROS Anwers Q&As like this one do not really work very well as bug reports.

**Comment by [guru_florida](https://answers.ros.org/users/49713/guru_florida/) on 2019-12-22**:
You're right. I thought the same after I wrote this and found the right repo ros2/rcl. Still worth keeping this for the next user though. ;)
https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/553